# Chaining ActiveRecord_Relation in PORO

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

In a Rails 5.1 app, I have a query object (PORO) named `CoolProducts`.

```
class CoolProducts
  def self.call(relation = Product.all)
  ...
  # return an instance of Product::ActiveRecord_Relation
  end
end
```

Now I need to limit the found `Product`s based on the fact the `name` matches a `string`.

The following works

```
CoolProducts.call.where("name ILIKE ?", "%#{string}%")
```

However, I'd like to encapsulate the matching login within the `CoolProducts` class allowing to do something like

```
CoolProducts.call.including_in_name(string)
```

But I'm not sure where to start from.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It will be difficult if you want any of your methods to be chainable or return ActiveRecord::Relation.

If you consider explicitly fetching the records when you're done chaining being ok, this should work:

```
class CoolProducts
  def initialize(relation)
    @relation = relation
  end

  def self.call(relation = Product.all)
    new(relation).apply_scopes
  end

  attr_reader :relation
  alias_method :fetch, :relation

  def including_in_name(string)
    tap { @relation = relation.where("name ILIKE ?", string) }
  end

  def apply_scopes
    tap { @relation = relation.where(price: 123) }
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
CoolProducts.call.including_in_name(string).fetch
```